# SQL Stock Tracking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a dbo.StockLocationHistoryTable that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.StockLocationHistory AS slh    

    StockIdentifier | DateScanned             | WarehouseLocation
    -------------------------------------------------
    72825           | 2016-07-03 16:41:24.077 | 854
    30509           | 2016-07-03 16:41:24.077 | 854
    30509           | 2016-07-05 08:22:10.056 | 854
    30509           | 2016-07-06 14:22:15.099 | 628
    30509           | 2016-07-08 15:28:22.542 | 628
    72825           | 2016-07-08 15:32:25.256 | 778
    30509           | 2016-07-10 18:22:24.556 | 854
```

The premise is that each time an employee does a stock take, a row is added for that product and the location the product is in. So from the table above we see that product 72825 was scanned on the 3rd in location 854 then scanned again on the 8th in location 778.

Unfortunately, the software doesn't put in a StockOUT record when it detects that a product is in a different location than it's previous scan. I'm attempting (unsuccessfully) to create a location ledger detailing the history of a location.

I am only concerned with when the stock is added to a location and removed from a location, not interim scans (EG: Row 3 in the first code block). I also need to detail as shown in code block 2, when the stock was detected in the new location as a StockOUT event.

What I need is the following:

```
DECLARE @WarehouseLocation INT = 854

[DateScanned]           | StockIdentifier | EventType | StockLevel
------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-07-03 16:41:24.077 | 30509           | StockIN   | 1
2016-07-03 16:41:24.077 | 72825           | StockIN   | 2
2016-07-06 14:22:15.099 | 30509           | StockOUT  | 1
2016-07-08 15:32:25.256 | 72825           | StockOUT  | 0
2016-07-10 18:22:24.556 | 30509           | StockIN   | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to think about other ways to obtain these data. The reason is that SQL get complicated and, in my opinion, is not very effective. You can think about the changes in the structure or table processing.

If not, perhaps counting the StockLevel will be easier to do at the application level (did not require an intermediate table).

The target table is renamed to @t, the code to be smaller. "@intermediate.id" introduced to correctly count StockLevel (because DateScanned not unique).
Last "ORDER BY" is to garantee right order (because "GROUP BY" does not garantee this for all cases).

```
declare @WarehouseLocation int = 854

declare @intermediate table(id int identity primary key, DateScanned datetime, StockIdentifier int, EventType char(8))

insert @intermediate
select tin.DateScanned, tin.StockIdentifier, 'StockIN' as EventType from @t tin
    where tin.WarehouseLocation = @WarehouseLocation
    and not exists(select * from @t t 
        where t.StockIdentifier = tin.StockIdentifier 
        and t.WarehouseLocation = @WarehouseLocation
        and t.DateScanned < tin.DateScanned
        and not exists(select * from @t tout 
            where tout.StockIdentifier = t.StockIdentifier
            and tout.DateScanned > t.DateScanned and tout.DateScanned < tin.DateScanned
            and tout.WarehouseLocation != @WarehouseLocation))
union all
select tout.DateScanned, tout.StockIdentifier, 'StockOUT' as EventType from @t tout
    where tout.WarehouseLocation != @WarehouseLocation
    and not exists(select * from @t t
        where t.StockIdentifier = tout.StockIdentifier 
        and t.WarehouseLocation != @WarehouseLocation
        and t.DateScanned < tout.DateScanned
        and not exists(select * from @t tin 
            where tin.StockIdentifier = t.StockIdentifier
            and tin.DateScanned > t.DateScanned and tin.DateScanned < tout.DateScanned
            and tin.WarehouseLocation = @WarehouseLocation))
order by DateScanned

select t.DateScanned, t.StockIdentifier, t.EventType,
    sum(case when prev.EventType = 'StockIn' then 1 else -1 end) as StockLevel
from @intermediate t left join @intermediate prev on prev.id <= t.id
group by t.DateScanned, t.StockIdentifier, t.EventType
order by t.DateScanned
```